# Passing Selected Image from UIImagePicker to a Second View Controller

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I've looked all over for a solution but haven't been able to find one.  I want to be able to select an Image from the UIImagePicker and have that image go to an ImageView in a Second View Controller.  I have a button that triggers an AlertView with options to get photos from camera or library.  It works fine if I want the selected image to go to an image view on the first view but I can't get it to work to have it go to a second view.  Any suggestions would be greatfully appreciated.  `

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

        var newImage = UIImage(named: "")
        @IBAction func libraryBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "beach.jpg" )
        imagePicker.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func addButton(sender: UIButton) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Get An Image", message: "Choose from below", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in

                        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
                        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in

                        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
                        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)



        }))


            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

        newImage = image


     performSegueWithIdentifier("VC2", sender: self)


      self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var secondViewController: VC2 = segue.destinationViewController as! VC2
        secondViewController.imageView.image = newImage




    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Swift but I do know ObjC, so I will try to explain:

Class 2 .h :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *myImageViewer;
```

Class 1 .m :

```
mySecondViewController.myImageViewer = [UIImageView new];
[mySecondViewController.myImageViewer setImage: newImage];
```

First you need to make the ImageView global to be able to access from other controllers. Then after you picked the `newImage`, you initialize memory to myImageViewer and give it the `newImage` you just picked, then load the viewController.

Hope this is what you needed to hear?